# InfluxDB Data Explorer: different results when re-running query?

Tags: influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Going through the [Queries and Data Model](https://awesome.influxdata.com/docs/part-2/querying-and-data-transformations/#queries-and-the-data-model) section of Time to Awesome (therefore you can tell I'm just getting started with InfluxDB), I've noticed a seemingly strange behaviour: once the data (as provided in the tutorial) is ingested, running exactly the same query repeatedly outputs different data every time.

Last time I ran, this was the output:
[image]
3 tables were returned.

Alright, let's try again:
[image]
Interesting, 5 tables were returned...

The tutorial itself states that 12 tables are created based on the input data.
So what's happening here? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I faced the same issue via using python client. I filed the issue [here][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/issues/453 I also faced this using the data explorer like you do too.